# Jquery change all borders on classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why is not `$( "demo" ).css("border", "1px solid #FFF");`working? Every other part of the function is working, but not that one. The class "demo" is a regular  from "page1.html".

```
<script>
var button = 0;
var activecolor = 0;
function pressbutton(a){
button = a;
var color1 = "#46B29D";
var color2 = "#F0CA4D";
var color3 = "#E37B40";
if (button === 1) {
activecolor = color1;
document.getElementById("button1").className = "activemenubutton";
document.getElementById("button2").className = "menubutton";
document.getElementById("button3").className = "menubutton";
} else if (button === 2){
activecolor = color2;
document.getElementById("button1").className = "menubutton";
document.getElementById("button2").className = "activemenubutton";
document.getElementById("button3").className = "menubutton";
} else if (button === 3){
activecolor = color3;
document.getElementById("button1").className = "menubutton";
document.getElementById("button2").className = "menubutton";
document.getElementById("button3").className = "activemenubutton";
}

document.getElementById("textholder").style.borderTop = "1px solid " + activecolor;
document.getElementById("textholder").style.borderBottom = "1px solid " + activecolor;
document.getElementById("textholder").style.color= activecolor;


$("#textholder").load("Page" + a + ".html");
$( "demo" ).css("border", "1px solid #FFF");

} //end of function

</script>
```

Comment: Is "demo" a class? If so you'll need to specify it with `$(".demo")`

Comment: I just found out, that the Script is overwritten by something else. I can see it turns  white in a couple of seconds before it goes to another color. What can be the reason for that? 
It is at the end of the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("demo")
```

hits all < demo > tags, in case they exists, which I'm sure don't. You're missing

```
$(".demo") or $("#demo")
```

to hit elements with class or id 'demo'.

On top of that, load() is an asynchronous function, so the css() call will usually fire before the page is loaded, therefore not modifying your element styles. You shold replace the load() and css() calls this way:

```
$("#placeholder").load("Page" + a + ".html" , function(){
   $(".demo").css('border' , '1px solid #FFF');
```

})

So you force the css assignement to wait until the content is loaded from the server.

Comment: does it make any difference I am using load-function, and the .demo is inside page1.html (which I include in my index)

Comment: It depends a lot wether you're loading that html server side or if you're loading it dinamically. If you're loading it dinamically AFTER that .css() call, it wont work.

Comment: Ok, i didn't see that load() function you said was the jQuery one. I'll update my answer to provide a possible solution.

Comment: If I want to add more classes to change, is that easy too?

Comment: Yes, just add the css changes to that callback function inside load()

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a full stop. `$( ".demo" ).css("border", "1px solid #FFF");`

Comment: I get no errors, but the border will not become white.